# Retrieve color programmatically from R.color

Tags: android, colors

I have a ListView which contains many TextViews, and one TextView should contain a different background color depending on the data that is retrieved.

Because i dont want to hardcode the colors i used R.color to set my Colors. That works nice, but i have to check manually for every color, because i am note able to get the colors like an HashMap. So my first Try was this:

```
    switch(line) {
    case "1":
        lineColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.line1);
    case "2":
        lineColor = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.line2);
    ....
    ....
    }
```

This seems far away from clean code, so i tried a different approach by using String-Arrays:

```
<string-array name="line_color_names">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    ....
</string-array>

<string-array name="line_color_values">
    <item>#e00023</item>
    <item>#ef9ec1</item>
    ....
</string-array>
```

In my AdapterClass i just created a HashMap and put this String-Arrays together:

```
    String[] line_color_names = context.getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.line_color_names);
    String[] line_color_values = context.getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.line_color_values);

    lineColors = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < line_color_names.length; i++) {
        lineColors.put(line_color_names[i], line_color_values[i]);
    }
```

So my Question is: Is this the only way to achieve this or is there another, ideally by taking colors directly from R.color?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question with sufficient details!

Comment: BTW, color name is in sequence, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get color ID by using resource name (`R.color.foo`) and resolve it at runtime:

```
public int getColorIdByResourceName(String name) {
  int color;
  try {
    Class res = R.color.class;
    Field field = res.getField( name );
    int color = field.getInt(null);
  } catch ( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return color;
}
```

and then

```
int colorId  = getColorIdByResourceName("foo21");
int colorVal = getResources().getColor(getColorIdByResourceName("foo21"));
```

Comment: I was formely `Integer` but I changed it before posting.

Comment: Errors in this code. int color = null; won't work. Also color = getColorValueByResourceName("R.color.foo21"); is wrong. it should be color = getColorValueByResourceName("foo21");

Comment: True. "haste makes waste" :/

Comment: I would make the method return `Color` object.

Comment: Me too, but that's OP exercise :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski and Rohit5k2: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Now my Code is much cleaner. And i followed Aleks G suggestion and returned a Color object.

Comment: I am not sure why but I am getting blue for my reads of green.

Comment: This is incorrect and returns the *id* of a color resource, not the integer value of the color. See answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29908380/1458948

Answer (score 0):

Your second solution seems good and isn't a hack exactly. You should be find with this.
But if you get your colour name dynamically then this code could be handy for you.

```
public static int getColorIDFromName(String name)
{
    int colorID = 0;

    if(name == null
            || name.equalsIgnoreCase("")
            || name.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class res = R.color.class;
        Field field = res.getField(name);
        colorID = field.getInt(null);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("getColorIDFromName", "Failed to get color id." + e);
    }

    return colorID;
}
```