# Retrieving color programmatically from R.color returns wrong colors

Tags: android, xml, colors

I am trying to take color names listed in a user's xml file and return the hexadecimal color.  I am using the code based off the post [Retrieve color programmatically from R.color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584922/retrieve-color-programmatically-from-r-color).  I know I am close because when I had a small set of colors in hash map with the names as keys it was working, but over 300 colors in the file and looking for 5 or 6 seems like wasted processing time.  The code below is what is being worked with, but I can include more if needed.

Example of user's xml file.

```
<Item>
    <Item_Name>Daily</Item_Name>
    <Price>400</Price>
    <Type>Entry</Type>
    <Color>Green</Color>
</Item>
```

colors.xml

```
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
```

Java:

```
 0   **pass in name from method call**
 1   Class res = R.color.class;
 2   Field field = res.getField( name );
 3   color = field.getInt(null);
```

When I run this as debug the results given are as follows:

```
0: name = "green"
1: res = tech.travis.poolpos.R$color
2: field = public static final int tech.travis.poolpos.R$color.green
3: color = 2131099743 (integer).  This translates to #&5f00067f,
     which is about a navy blue with an opacity of about 37%.
```

The integer that should be returned for green should be -16744448, not 2131099743.

How, if possible, do I take a name as a string and match it and return a color listed in colors.xml?

Comment: I think that's the id of the colour, not the colour itself. To get the colour you need `getResources().getColor(field.getInt(null))`

Comment: That worked William.  Thank you.  Please post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the id of the colour, not the colour itself. To get the colour you need `getResources().getColor(field.getInt(null));` instead.

Everything on `R` is an ID. That is why we have methods like `getColor` or `getDrawable` which take as argument `R.color.my_color` or `R.drawable.my_drawable`.

Answer (score 1):

resources.getColor is deprecated. the new way to get a color is:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color_name)
```